# Modify and return closure

Tags: rust, closures, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to make a function to do the following:
accept a closure `f` of the form `fn(T) -> T`
return a closure of the form `fn(T, bool) -> T`, that conditionally performs `f` depending on the bool parameter.

I come from a haskell-ish background, and in Haskell this would be something like this:

```Haskell
conditionally :: (a -> a) -> a -> Bool -> a
conditionally f x True = f x
conditionally f x False = x
```

Translating that to something more rust-like:

```Haskell
conditionally :: ((t) -> t) -> ((t, Bool) -> t)
conditionally f = \(x, b) -> if b then (f x) else (x)
```

I tried the following in rust:

```rust
fn conditionally<T>(f: &'static (dyn Fn(T) -> T + 'static)) -> Box<dyn Fn(T, bool) -> T> {
    Box::new(&|x, b| if b { f(x) } else { x } )
}
```

and was helpfully told to use the `move` keyword to ensure the closure takes ownership of `f`. However, the following still doesn't work:

```rust
fn conditional<T>(f: &'static (dyn Fn(T) -> T + 'static)) -> Box<dyn Fn(T, bool) -> T> {
    Box::new(&move|x, b| if b { f(x) } else { x } )
}
```

I'm getting the following error (this also appeared prior to adding `move`):

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
   --> src/main.rs:216:5
    |
216 |     Box::new(&move|x, b| if b { f(x) } else { x } )
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^-----------------------------------^^
    |     |         |
    |     |         temporary value created here
    |     returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

I'm thinking that the 'data owned by the current function' is either the closure I've defined, or the `f` that I've moved, but I can't get my head around how it all fits together.
As a smoke check, I made sure I'm able to box simpler closures that I define in the function body, and the following compiles:

```rust
fn conditional_increment() -> Box<dyn Fn(i32, bool) -> i32> {
    Box::new(&|x, b| if b { x + 1 } else { x } )
}
```

What am I missing here? Is this possible in rust?
I'm also wondering if there's a more specific name for what I'm trying to do than simply higher-order functions, as I'm struggling to find resources on this kind of problem.

Update: I've realised that "currying in rust" would have been a good term to search for. While this isn't an example of currying, it would use the same language features, and would have led me to the answer given by vallentin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're attempting to return a boxed reference to a closure defined within the `conditional` function. Which you can't do, given that the closure only lives for the duration of the call. Instead you can return the closure itself, and in short just have to remove the `&`, i.e. turn `&move |x, b| ...` into `move |x, b| ...`.

```rust
fn conditional<T>(f: &'static (dyn Fn(T) -> T + 'static)) -> Box<dyn Fn(T, bool) -> T> {
    Box::new(move |x, b| if b { f(x) } else { x })
}
```

However, the more idiomatic way to write what you're attempting, which is to use generics and a type parameter for the closure. Check out:

- [Rust By Example - (Closures) As input parameters](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/fn/closures/input_parameters.html)
- [Rust By Example - (Closures) As output parameters](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/fn/closures/output_parameters.html).

In short, you could rewrite it into this:

```rust
fn conditional<F, T>(f: F) -> Box<dyn Fn(T, bool) -> T>
where
    F: Fn(T) -> T + 'static,
    T: 'static,
{
    Box::new(move |x, b| if b { f(x) } else { x })
}
```

You can actually also do without the box, and use the [`impl Trait` syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/trait-system/impl-trait-for-returning-complex-types-with-ease.html).

```rust
fn conditional<F, T>(f: F) -> impl Fn(T, bool) -> T
where
    F: Fn(T) -> T,
{
    move |x, b| if b { f(x) } else { x }
}
```

*You can also use the `impl Trait` syntax for parameters, which the links shows, but personally I find it to noisy when dealing with closuring.*

Using it the boils down to something as simple as this:

```rust
let f = conditional(move |x| x * 2);
println!("{}", f(2, false)); // Prints `2`
println!("{}", f(2, true));  // Prints `4`
```

Comment: Great answer. Why do you pass `conditional` a _reference_ to the closure in the last example? And why does that even compile? It compiles without the reference, too, but given that `F` is not a reference, I'd expect the call to `conditional` not to compile as written.

Comment: @user4815162342 because both `|x| {x}` and `&|x| {x}` implement `Fn(T) -> T`, and that's the only thing that this function  requires of its argument.

Comment: That's true, but in my case it was actually just a typo, I didn't mean to have `&` :)

Comment: Knowing this, I'm surprised that my `conditional_increment` example worked at all, though I'll admit I'm unsure how `Box::new` handles its parameter if it's a reference.